# Why is innodb strict mode not enabling?

Tags: mysql

I tried adding this line in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` (Ubuntu)

```
innodb_strict_mode = 1
```

This is within the [mysqld] section, where I have seen this line in other examples. I know this config file is being read at startup because I get errors if I type in nonsense.

Nevertheless, SHOW VARIABLES lists this variable as OFF and apparently I can insert rows without specifying my non-default fields.

Why isn't this variable being set?

I have tried `=on` instead of `=1`, no difference. The config is otherwise unmodified from the installation default, AFAIK, full text [here](http://pastebin.com/YzakSEFf).

Answer (score 9):

You can set this `SESSION` variable from the command line:

```
mysql> show variables like '%strict%';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| innodb_strict_mode | OFF   |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Then, you do this:

```
mysql> set innodb_strict_mode = ON;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Then, to check:

```
mysql> show variables like '%strict%';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| innodb_strict_mode | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+
```

Then, on exiting and reconnecting, and rechecking the variable, it is again OFF - the default. Use `SET GLOBAL innodb_strict_mode = ON` if you don't want it to reset after logging off. But, setting it in the client will not make the change stick after a reboot of the server.

Edit `my.cnf` - I've never seen or touched `mysqld.cnf`.

Put the line(s) below in the [mysqld] section of my.cnf.

```
sql_mode    = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY"
innodb_strict_mode = ON
```

(I recommend the sql_mode line also - otherwise, for example, certain `GROUP BY` queries will return (ahem...) anomalous results).

Bounce the server - and relog in.

```
mysql> show variables like '%strict%';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| innodb_strict_mode | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

It's all in the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_strict_mode).

> You can turn innodb_strict_mode ON or OFF on the command line when you
>   start mysqld, or in the configuration file my.cnf or my.ini. You can
>   also enable or disable innodb_strict_mode at runtime with the
>   statement SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] innodb_strict_mode=mode, where mode is
>   either ON or OFF. Changing the GLOBAL setting requires the SUPER
>   privilege and affects the operation of all clients that subsequently
>   connect. Any client can change the SESSION setting for
>   innodb_strict_mode, and the setting affects only that client.

Maybe you don't have the `SUPER` privilege? Log in and run `SHOW GRANTS` to find out.