# Is there a way to set innodb_strict_mode on AWS RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Moving an old app that was set up 8 years ago. I've run `mysqldump` and now I'm trying to load it into a new MySQL database running on AWS RDS.

There was a mismatch in types. There was a text field that has too much information in it, but apparently the limits were not strictly enforced on the old database. I think I can fix this if I can do this:

```
set innodb_strict_mode = OFF;
```

I read this carefully and followed the directions:

[Why is innodb strict mode not enabling?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135844/why-is-innodb-strict-mode-not-enabling)

But if I try:

```
set innodb_strict_mode = OFF;
```

I get:

> ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the
> SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for
> this operation

I've spent hours trying to figure out if there is a way I can get the right privileges on RDS, but I can't find anything. Does anyone know?

This page makes it sound hopeless:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/mysqldump-error-rds-mysql-mariadb/

It says:

"*The command for the line referenced in the error message requires SUPER privilege(s) that aren't provided in RDS DB instances.*"

If that is true, then is there some work around? I can't simply throw away millions of records.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set this via a param group. See [Working With Param Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html)

tldr;

1. create new param group
2. edit `innodb_strict_mode`, set to 0 for off, 1 for on
3. modify db instance and apply new param group to it
4. reboot instance